# The chip close button won't adhere to css

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

[image]

I can't seem to get the close x on the chip to appear and adhere to the .css.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-label>City</ion-label>
      <input placeholder="Enter city" #searchPlaces>
    <div class="selected-places">
    <ion-chip *ngFor="let intPlace of intPlaces">
      <ion-label>{{ intPlace }}</ion-label>
      <button (click)="deletePlace(intPlace)">
        <img src="assets/img/ic-small-close.png"/>
      </button>
    </ion-chip>
  </div> 
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

And css

```css
.selected-places {
    ion-label{
      width: 79.4px;
      font-family: Gotham;
      font-size: 14.2px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      font-stretch: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      text-align: left;
      color: black !important;
      overflow-y: visible !important;
     }

     ion-chip{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 20px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        margin: 3px;
        img{
            width: 3px !important;
            height: 3px !important;
            float: right !important;
        }
    }
```

[image: Can't see 'x' img]

For some reason, I can't get the x to show on the chip.  I've tried playing the css but it won't appear on the chip.

The grey verticle bar under the 'L' is supposed to be the 'x' img.

Comment: I think you missed a closing `}` in the css part.. Probably just a typo in the question

Comment: Yes, it's a typo in the question.  The closing bracket is in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by abandoning the ion-chip all together and just using  tags.  I've encountered several problems that were resolved by NOT using ION specific elements and just using the regular html counterparts.